# Camel Zookeeper Component not found in activeMQs embedded Camel Modul

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

On 3 virtual machines running Zookeeper + ActiveMQ.
ActiveMQ Version 5.15.9 with Camel Version 2.19.5

Now, I'm using the embedded Camel EIP Framework in ActiveMQ.
I want to get a specific node from Zookeeper based on an event.

```xml
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <!-- You can use Spring XML syntax to define the routes here using the <route> element -->
        <route>
            <description>Read zookeeper variant 1</description>
            <from uri="activemq:example.zoo1"/>
            <pollEnrich>
               <constant>zookeeper://localhost:2182/some/node/99</constant>
            </pollEnrich>
            <to uri="activemq:example.zooRead1"/>
        </route>
        <route>
            <description>Read zookeeper variant 2</description>
            <from uri="activemq:example.zoo2"/>
            <pollEnrich>
               <constant>zookeeper:znode1:2182,znode2:2182,znode3:2182/some/node/99</constant>
            </pollEnrich>
            <to uri="activemq:example.zooRead2"/>
        </route>
</camelContext>
```

In the Log File following exception occured with variant 1

```
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: zookeeper://localhost:2182/some/node/99 due to: No component found with scheme: zookeeper
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:729)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.resolveEndpoint(ExchangeHelper.java:92)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.PollEnricher.resolveEndpoint(PollEnricher.java:343)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.PollEnricher.process(PollEnricher.java:201)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)[camel-core-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:112)[camel-jms-2.19.5.jar:2.19.5]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719)[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649)[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1168)[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1160)[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1057)[spring-jms-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)[:1.8.0_222]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)[:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_222]
2019-10-01 15:06:05,652 | DEBUG | Message exchange has failed: so breaking out of pipeline for exchange: Exchange[ID-Monkey-34387-1569942241018-0-1] Exception: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: zookeeper://localhost:2182/some/node/99 due to: No component found with scheme: zookeeper | org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline | Camel (camel) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[example.zoo1]
2019-10-01 15:06:05,690 | WARN  | Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException - Failed to resolve endpoint: zookeeper://localhost:2182/some/node/99 due to: No component found with scheme: zookeeper] | org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener | Camel (camel) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[example.zoo1]
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: zookeeper://localhost:2182/some/node/99 due to: No component found with scheme: zookeeper
```

[Camel Zookeeper Component](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/b9a3117f19dd19abd2ea8b789c42c3e86fe4c488/components/camel-zookeeper/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/zookeeper/ZooKeeperEndpoint.java)

Comment: Have you added `camel-zookeper` dependency? `<dependency><groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId><artifactId>camel-zookeeper</artifactId><version>2.19.5</version></dependency>`

Comment: There is small chance that you can add the `camel-zookeeper` jar into `lib` folder in `ACTIVEMQ_HOME`, but I have never tried it. Custom build of ActiveMQ with modification of [activemq-camel/pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-camel/pom.xml) should almost certainly work.

Comment: I added the jar into the lib folder, the ResolveEndpointFailedException is gone. I'm wondering that the component is not already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution works as [@Bedla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8576169/bedla) wrote.

Copy the Jar in the `ACTIVEMQ_HOME/lib` folder and it works as expceted.